# Import variable from external file python

Tags: javascript, python, file

I translate some JS files using js2py library. I need to get, from the newly created python files, a variable which has the same name in every file.

```
with os.scandir(path=r'path_to_folder') as folder:
       for file in folder:
            if file.name.endswith('.js'):
                new_name = os.path.basename(file) + ".py"
                path = os.path.basename(file)
                js2py.translate_file(path, new_name)
                print("Translated")
                print()
```

It works to translate every JS file into python, but I need those variables and importing from new_name('from new_name import var') doesn't work. Is there another way of getting those variables?

Comment: Does `from new_name import *` work?

Comment: I tried at first like that, but python doesn't recognize new_name. Now I try to translate js files in just one python file and import dynamically the variable, but it works only for the first js file.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on [Js2Py GitHub](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py).

```
>>> print(js2py.translate_js('var $ = 5'))
from js2py.pyjs import *
# setting scope
var = Scope( JS_BUILTINS )
set_global_object(var)

# Code follows:
var.registers(['$'])
var.put('$', Js(5.0))
```